# Drag formula from active cell to the right where row is variable but column is set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the formula from a cell in column C straight across to column F. I always want to copy the formula from column C and drag through column F, however the row should be determined by the active cell.  Once the formula is dragged across I want to drag those formulas down to the last row with data in column B.

So far my VBA from my recorded macro looks like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('Item Setup'!C2:C40,MATCH(R[-8]C2,'Item Setup'!C2,0),MATCH(R4C,'Item Setup'!R4C2:R4C40,0))"
    Range("C13").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:F13"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C13:F13").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C13:F" & lastRow)
    Range("C13:F13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you can do this in one go, and also without having to use Select or Autofill.

Not generally advisable though to base a macro on the active cell.

```
Sub x()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C"), Cells(lastRow, "F"))
    .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('Item Setup'!C2:C40,MATCH(R[-8]C2,'Item Setup'!C2,0),MATCH(R4C,'Item Setup'!R4C2:R4C40,0))"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm... that didn't seem to work for me.  My formula is starting in cell C8 even though there is a value in B16.  Also the formulas are being copied down from row 8 to row 13 leaving rows 14:16 blank even though cells B14:B16 all have values in them.

Comment: Have you had a look to see what's going on? What's the value of lastRow?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, stay away from  `ActiveCell`, `Selection` and `Select`, instead use fully qualified `Range` and `Worksheet` objects.

**Second**, you can set your entire range where you want to add your formula, and then fill it at once, without dragging or anything like it.

***Modified Code***

```
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim AnchorRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") ' modify with your sheet's name

With Sht
    Set AnchorRng = ActiveCell ' .Range("C13") ' start point of your formula

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column B

    .Range(AnchorRng, .Cells(LastRow, "F")).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('Item Setup'!C2:C40,MATCH(R[-8]C2,'Item Setup'!C2,0),MATCH(R4C,'Item Setup'!R4C2:R4C40,0))"
End With
```

**Note**: this code is not debugging your formula, just assigning to your entire range.

Comment: The start point of my formula won't be C13 every time.  That will vary based on the first empty cell in column C.